# xml intellisense with Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellisense

Please suggest some free tools or some in build feature in Eclipse for intellisense of xml.

I am using Eclipse Europa which is for EE java developers.

```
    <?xml version ="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
        <tests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://jtestcase.sourceforge.net/dtd/jtestcase2.xsd">
        </tests>
```

Xml code above is part of xml file i am working upon. I am expecting eclipse to suggest me tags based upon xsd specified above. I am using ctrl+space for suggestion of new tag. Please suggest if i am using wrong key for intellisense or am i missing some tool or plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Is your network setting configured properly in eclipse.. because eclipse will load xsd file first.

Comment: how to see network setting. by the way its working fine now. I must have made some mistake.

Comment: network setting are stored in eclipse prefernces..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me - I get prompted to enter a  or  element.  I'm using Eclipse Helios.  I would have guessed that Europa had the same functionality, although I wouldn't put all my money on that.

Is it possible that you're not using the XML editor, that instead you're opening up the doc with a different Eclipse editor?  The icon in the editor tab should have an "X" (for "XML") in it.  (Again, I'm not sure how far back in versions that icon is available.)

You could try right-clicking on the the doc in the Package Explorer, and seeing what editors pop up in the "Open With..." submenu, and picking the XML editor, just to make sure.